# CKEDITOR 5 set body `id`

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is there a way to set the `id` attribute of the body of a CKEDITOR 5 ClassicEditor?

In cke4, there was a config option `BodyID` you could set when creating the editor instance, but I was unable to find something similar for cke5 in the docs or on SO.

I need to attach `Countable.js` to the editor to perform wordcount and feed that info to other parts of the code (over which I have no control)

I may have multiple editors active on the page at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, CKE5 does not play well with `CountableJS` when deleting text using the backspace key. The live wordcount does not get updated as it would in a normal `textarea`.

I used a different solution:

```
editor.document.on('changesDone`, (evt,data) => {
  Countable.once(editorelement,callback())
});
```

This seems to work for backspace/delete as well as text input and `setData()`.

Answer (score 1):

In CKEditor 5 the root editable element can be easily retrieved using the API:

```
editor.ui.view.editable.element
```

See:

[image]

You don't need to set any ids – just get the element and pass it to Countable.js:

```
const callback = counter => console.log(counter);
const area = editor.ui.view.editable.element;

Countable.live(area, callback);
```